# gdal_merge - what use does the -"init" option have?

Tags: gdal-merge

Looking at the gdal documenation for gdal_merge the "-init" option pre-initializes output bands with values. I assume this means that the whole band is assigned a certain value before the gdal_merge command runs.

What advantage does this give me and which use-cases are there for such an option?

Answer (score 1):

I have utilized the `-createonly -init`options at least for these purposes:

- An empty image without real data is often perfect as test data. It has the same extents, pixel size etc. than the original one but it can be compressed very effectively. When all pixels are initialized into fixed value no confidential content remains in the image and it may be possible to share that clean image for debugging purposes because it uncovers only the location. Even that can be obscured but it may make debugging harder especially if the issue has connection to coordinate systems.
- Image that is initialized into red or blue or something stands out better to eye than pure black. With blue, red etc. source images it is also easy to check visually the results of some processes.
- If the final mosaic will contain empty space between some source images, the color of the background can be set first. After that user can update the mosaic image by image with for example gdalwarp.

Nowadays there is also another alternative for creating and initializing images, the gdal_create utility https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_create.html. However, gdal_merge with `-createonly` and `-init` may still be handy for initializing the output for an image mosaic. If users want to do the same with gdal_create they should first create a virtual mosaic with gdalbuildvrt and then use the VRT file as on input file `-if` for gdal_create.